# PHP fread quotes

Tags: php

I have this block of code

```
$file = 'courses/' . $fourth;    
$whatToRead = @fopen($file, "r") or die ("Could not read file");  
$file_contents = fread($whatToRead, filesize($file));  
$new_file_contents = nl2br($file_contents);
```

and when it returns the text from the file, I echo it and all of the quotes return as â€™ instead of ' does anyone know how to fix this

Comment: Read about "Encoding".

Comment: try `@fopen($file, "rb")` instead of `@fopen($file, "r")`

Comment: @EL: doesn't matter. it's a display problem. fread doesn't care if it's multibyte or single-byte text. it just slurps ALL of the bytes its told to.